How to debug network calls in Node.js application running in VS code
I'm developing a Node.js application using VS Code and installed @azure/msal-node package. I'm calling the acquireTokenOnBehalfOf function to acquire a token for my application, which internally makes a request to a Microsoft API. I'd like to know which Microsoft API is being called and what the payload of the request looks like.
Need guidance on how I can debug these network calls and inspect the requests made to Microsoft APIs while running the application in VS Code?
